# Prompt блокирует загрузку страницы

Tags: javascript

В моем JS коде сначала отображается вопрос из prompt, и страница загружается только после того, как я отвечаю на вопрос.

Как сделать так, чтобы сначала загрузилась страница, значение promptDiv было пустым, а после ответа на вопрос там появился текст?

```
let adv = document.querySelector('.adv');
let promptDiv = document.querySelector('.prompt');

document.body.style.background = 'url(./img/apple_true.jpg)'

let answer = prompt('Как вы относитесь к технике Яблоко?', 'Нормально');
promptDiv.textContent = answer;
```

Comment: в js есть функция, которая срабатывает при загрузке страницы, в эту функцию пиши свой промпт

Comment: Обратите внимание на знак "галочка" слева от ответов на Ваши вопросы. Этот знак сделан для Вас. Пользуйтесь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let adv = document.querySelector('.adv'), promptDiv = document.querySelector('.prompt');

document.body.style.background = 'url(./img/apple_true.jpg)'

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  let answer = prompt('Как вы относитесь к технике Яблоко?', 'Нормально');
  promptDiv.textContent = answer;
});
```